# How to split functions of a single class across multiple files in Lua?

Tags: lua

What is the proper way to split multiple functions of a single class across files in Lua?

In the following example I would like to split the math and spelling functions across separate files.

```
CardsScene = Core.class(Sprite) 

function CardsScene:basicMathInit()
end

function CardsScene:basicMathIdle()
end

function CardsScene:basicMathAnswer()
end

function CardsScene:basicSpellingInit()
end

function CardsScene:basicSpellingIdle()
end

function CardsScene:basicSpellingAnswer()
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't declare `CardsScene` as a local in any of your files, it's a global.

Any code that runs after you set its value, will use the table created by `Core.class(Sprite)`. In Lua, functions are not declared. They are values created at runtime. When you run a statement like:

```
function CardsScene:basicMathAnswer()
end
```

it creates a function value and assigns it to the `basicMathAnswer` field in the table referred to by the value that the expression `CardsScene` currently evaluates to.

So, go ahead and move any or all of those statements with function definitions and assignments to as many files as you want. Just be sure to execute them all, after the one that assigns the global variable `CardsScene`.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself familiar with Lua modules and the standard function `require`

https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require

You can execute Lua files like functions.

File A.lua:

```
print("hello this is from file A")
```

File B.lua:

```
require("A")
print("and this is from file B")
```

once you run B.lua you will get the following output:

*hello this is from file A*

*and this is from file B*

Once you understood what's happening you can implement your table members across multiple files.

I would recommend to not split one table across multiple files. I'd rather have a separate table for Math and Spelling and a third table that combines them to a CardsScene. Not just 2 working on the same table.

Comment: I'm familiar with `require`,  but hadn't used it quite like this before.  Typically I would split across classes ; in my current case though I'm working inside a scene management system that requires a lot of time and overhead to transition scenes.  In this situation switching scenes would be an unbearable user experience,  so I'm looking at other options of still trying to keep my code organized and easy to maintain.

Comment: @bigtunacan not sure if I fully understand what you want to achieve. you don't have to switch your scene. just have 1 interface that gets it's implementations from 2 required files.